# Improve efficiency of PIG Script

Tags: apache-pig, hadoop2

**DATASET:**
I have a data set (data.txt) in (ID, Category) format as given below:

```
    01,X
    02,Y
    03,X
    04,Y
    05,X
    06,X
    07,Z
    08,Z
    09,X
    10,Z
```

**Objective:**
The objective is to find out which category has the maximum number of IDs without using UDF.

**One Approach:**
I have tried multiple times and concluded that this can be achived by the followins set of PIG statements

```
 A1 = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (ID:int , Category:chararray);
 A2 = DISTINCT A1;
 A3 = GROUP A2 BY Category;
 A4 = FOREACH A3 GENERATE group AS Category, COUNT(A2.ID) AS Number;
 A5 = GROUP A4 ALL;
 A6 = FOREACH A5 GENERATE MAX(A4.Number);
 A7 = FILTER A4 by Number == A6.$0;
 A8 = FOREACH A7 GENERATE Category;
 DUMP A8;
```

**Request:**
Although these statements give the desired result, I am not convinced with its efficiency.
As I am new to PIG, I am not sure if there are any inbuilt functions which can perform such tasks to output the corresponding values of the minimum or maximum value of from a table.

My request is to know if this can be achived in any less number of steps.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping sort the grouping by counts in descending order and get the topmost record.

```
A1 = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (ID:int , Category:chararray);
A2 = DISTINCT A1;
A3 = GROUP A2 BY Category;
A4 = FOREACH A3 GENERATE group AS Category, COUNT(A2.ID) AS Number;
A5 = ORDER A4 BY Number DESC;
A6 = LIMIT A5 1;
DUMP A6.$0;
```

Comment: This script will work f9 if the data set have only one max value if you have multiple max value it will not produce correct result..